# How to disable non-breaking space

Tags: babel, french

I have a document written partly in French, partly in another language. For various reasons, I want to use `babel` and the document class roughly as shown. But I want to disable the French orthographic rule of placing a non-breaking space before ";", ":", "?" and "!". How can I achieve this? Here is an `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Here it is; I want to remove the non-breaking space in this section: Don't I? Of course I do!
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\frenchbsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}`

Comment: @touhami Want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't think so, Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
\frenchbsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}
```

will do.

Complete (minimal) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\frenchbsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}

\begin{document}

Here it is; I want to remove the non-breaking space
in this section: Don't I? Of course I do!

\end{document}
```

[image]